# Does $\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\left(\ln{\frac{k+1}{k-1}}-\frac{2}{k}\right)$ diverge or converge?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, real-numbers

> Does $$\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\left(\ln{\frac{k+1}{k-1}}-\frac{2}{k}\right)$$ diverge or converge?

It's clear that $f(x)>0 \ \forall \ x\in[2,\infty).$ The function $f(x)=\ln{\frac{x+1}{x-1}}-\frac{2}{x}$ has derivative

$$f'(x)=-\frac{2}{x^2(x^2-1)}<0 \ \forall \ x \in [2,\infty).$$

So we can use the integral comparison criteria. We have that

$$\int_{2}^{\infty}\left(\ln{\frac{x+1}{x-1}}-\frac{2}{x}\right) dx=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_2^n\left(\ln{(1+x)-\ln{(1-x)}}-\frac{2}{x}\right)dx.
$$

I know this integral converges to a fixed value but it's tedious to compute. Are there other comparison tests that would work here?

Comment: You must start at $k=2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write that
$$
\frac{k+1}{k-1}=1+\frac{2}{k-1}\text{ and}\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)\underset{(0^{+})}{=}\frac{1}{k}+o\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)
$$
Hence it comes
$$
\ln\left(\frac{k+1}{k-1}\right)-\frac{2}{k}=\frac{2}{k-1}-\frac{2}{k}+o\left(\frac{1}{k-1}\right)=\frac{2}{k\left(k-1\right)}+o\left(\frac{1}{k^2}\right)
$$
Finally

$$
\ln\left(\frac{k+1}{k-1}\right)-\frac{2}{k}\underset{(+\infty)}{\sim}\frac{2}{k^2}$$
Or the series $\displaystyle \sum_{ k \geq 1}^{ }\frac{1}{k^2}$ converges, so as your series.

Comment: How do you get from $o(1/(k-1))$ to $o(1/k^2)$?

Comment: The rest of the taylor's series is negligeable compare to this one term. But you can let 1/k(k-1) instead of 1/k^2

Comment: Does that reallt suffice to say? If we have that $$\ln\left(\frac{k+1}{k-1}\right)-\frac{2}{k} = \frac{2}{k^2-k}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^3}\right)$$ then one could say 

$$\frac{2}{k^2-k}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^3}\right) \geq \frac{2}{k^2} + O\left(\frac{1}{k^3}\right),$$

But here one can't use the comparison theorem despite that $2/k^2$ is convergent.

Comment: You still have the equivalent which helps you conclude that it is convergent. But minorant by a convergent series does not help you

Answer (score 3):

First the sum should start at $k=2$. By Telescoping sum we have 
$$\sum_{k=2}^{n}\left(\ln{\frac{k+1}{k-1}}-\frac{2}{k}\right) =\color{blue}{\sum_{k=2}^{n}\left(\ln(k+1)-\ln(k)\right)}+\color{red}{\sum_{k=2}^{n}\left(\ln(k)-\ln(k-1)\right)} -\sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac{2}{k} \\= \color{blue}{\ln(n+1)-\ln(2)}+\color{red}{\ln(n)} -\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2}{k}+2\\= 2\left(  \ln(n) -\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}\right) + 2-\ln2 +\ln{\frac{n+1}{n}} \to -2\gamma +2-\ln2$$

where $\gamma$ is the [Euler Mascheroni's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant) constant. That is

$$\color{blue}{\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\left(\ln{\frac{k+1}{k-1}}-\frac{2}{k}\right)=-2\gamma +2-\ln2}$$

Comment: @OlivierOloa thanks correction made

Answer (score 0):

Set $y=x-1\ge 1$. Then
$$
\log\frac{x+1}{x-1}=\log\left(1+\frac{2}{y}\right)=2\left(\frac{1}{y}-\frac{1+o(1)}{y^2}\right).
$$
Therefore
$$
2\sum_{y=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{y}-\frac{1+o(1)}{y^2}\right)-\frac{1}{y+1} < \infty.
$$

Comment: I dont understand this. Isn't the expansion $$\frac{2}{y}-2\left(\frac{1}{y}-\frac{1}{y^2}+O(\frac{1}{y^3})\right)?$$ What is $o(1)$?

Comment: Modulo the sign, what you wrote is correct and stronger than mine (even if it is not needed). Indeed
$$
\frac{1}{y^2}-O(\frac{1}{y^3})=\frac{1+o(1)}{y^2}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

If you use the integral for the logarithm,

$$\ln{k+1\over k-1}=\int_{k-1}^{k+1}{dx\over x}$$

and interpret the integral as the area beneath the curve $y={1\over x}$, then you can see, from a sketch of the curve, that

$${2\over k}\lt\int_{k-1}^{k+1}{dx\over x}\lt{1\over2}\left({1\over k-1}+{1\over k} \right)+{1\over2}\left({1\over k}+{1\over k+1} \right)$$

hence

$$0\lt\ln\left(k+1\over k-1\right)-{2\over k}\lt{1\over2}\left({1\over k-1}-{1\over k} \right)-{1\over2}\left({1\over k}-{1\over k+1} \right)$$

It follows that

$$0\lt\sum_{k=2}^\infty\left(\ln\left(k+1\over k-1\right)-{2\over k}\right)\lt{1\over2}\sum_{k=2}^\infty\left({1\over k-1}-{1\over k} \right)-{1\over2}\sum_{k=2}^\infty\left({1\over k}-{1\over k+1} \right)={1\over2}\cdot1-{1\over2}\cdot{1\over2}={1\over4}$$

Note, this accords with the exact value in Guy Fsone's answers, $$-2\gamma+2-\ln2\approx-2(0.577)+2-0.693=0.153$$